# onClick not working on all the clicks

Tags: onclick, addclass

I have these functions to change my backgrounds but the onClick event only works once or one of the four  does not work when page loads.
I know "return false" stops the functions but when I use the code without them, the background loads but returns to the original one.
Someone can tell me why?

```
 window.onload = init;
 function init(){
    document.getElementById("bg01").onclick = mudaBG01;
    function mudaBG01(){
    $("body").addClass("bg01");
   return false;
  }


    document.getElementById("bg02").onclick = mudaBG02;
    function mudaBG02(){
    $("body").addClass("bg02");
    return false;
  }


document.getElementById("bg03").onclick = mudaBG03;
function mudaBG03(){
$("body").addClass("bg03");
return false;
}


document.getElementById("bg04").onclick = mudaBG04;
function mudaBG04(){
$("body").addClass("bg04");
return false;
}

 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("bg04").onclick =  new Function("mudaBG04()");
```

and define all function mudaBG04() out side of init() function.

Comment: background loads but still returning to the original one =\

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
onclick= mudaBG01
```

to

```
onclick="mudaBG01()"
```

Comment: it does not load the background this way

Answer (score 0):

Done. I changed my JS functions to:

```
$("#bg01").click(function(){
$("body").css('background', 'url(../images/bg02.jpg)');
return false;
})


$("#bg02").click(function(){
$("body").css('background', 'url(../images/bg03.jpg)');
return false;
})


$("#bg03").click(function(){
$("body").css('background', 'url(../images/bg07.jpg)');
return false;
})


$("#bg04").click(function(){
$("body").css('background', 'url(../images/bg08.jpg)');
return false;
})
```

thank you  all =]